# Оставляете ли вы пасхалки в коде, если да то какие?

Tags: любой-язык

К примеру я делал пасхалку на определенное последовательность действий на странице после которых бегунок загрузки становился не процентно зависим, а равнялся количеству загружаемых байт и после того как он превышал 100% он начинал расти дальше сбивая все элементы дизайна на своем пути :D

Comment: @Зонтик, я понимаю ваше стремление удалить "ненужные" метки, но метка [tag:чистый-код] тут точно никаким боком к вопросу не относится.

Comment: @insolor просто показалось, что вопрос об этом... Надо тогда какую-то другую метку сюда прикрутить... Может быть [любой-язык]?

Comment: @Зонтик мне кажется лучше оставить как есть, тут не на что особо менять. Вопрос в идеале бы еще закрыть.

Answer (score 14):

У меня пасхалки всегда получаются случайно, но мой начальник почему-то ругается и называет их багами... =\

Comment: "перекуём баги на фичи!" :))

Answer (score 4):

Если не рассматривать бэкдоры и прочие гадости, пасхалок почти не оставляю. 
Иногда - веселые комментарии к коду.

Чаще всего, пасхалки хорошо, когда багов в коде нет вообще. Иначе выглядит как розовый бантик на разбитом запорожце. В большом проекте полностью избежать багов весьма сложно, так что остаются маленькие и простые вещи, коих очень немного, ибо все они так или иначе реализованы фреймворками.

Из безобидного - гоняющаяся за курсором летучая мышь, возможность расстрелять портрет онлайн-консультанта(увы, сейчас только в архивах), глупые вопросы на глупые действия: "Вы правда хотите просмотреть все 850000 предложений на одной странице?!"

Comment: В нашем проекте перед окошком с таблицей в особо тяжёлых случаях был вопрос

-- Вы правда хотите вывести *n* Гб данных на экран?

Comment: Вот как-то так. Причем далее можно честно выслать юзеру данные при положительном ответе.